# Update one mysql database from another

Tags: php, mysql

I'm a little of a rookie in the MySQL part of this. I think i am on the right path with the query and connecting to the two databses, but Im a bit unclear on how to execute the query over two databases. Can someone send me in the right direction?

Here is what I have so far:

```
<?php
    $dbh1 = mysql_connect('localhost', 'tendesig', 'password') or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");
    $dbh2 = mysql_connect('localhost', 'tendesig', 'password', true) or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");

    mysql_select_db('tendesig_dev', $dbh1);
    mysql_select_db('tendesig_production', $dbh2);

    $query = "UPDATE 
                tendesig_dev.euid0_hikashop_product, 
                tendesig_production.euid0_hikashop_product 
            SET 
                tendesig_dev.euid0_hikashop_product.product_quantity = tendesig_production.euid0_hikashop_product.product_quantity
            WHERE 
                'tendesig_dev.euid0_hikashop_product.product_id = tendesig_production.euid0_hikashop_product.product_id";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

`$dbh1` and `$dbh2` are **MySQL link identifiers** not **DB names**, you should replace them in the query:

```
<?php
    $dbh1 = mysql_connect('localhost', 'tendesig', 'password') or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");
    $dbh2 = mysql_connect('localhost', 'tendesig', 'password', true) or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");

    mysql_select_db('tendesig_dev', $dbh1);
    mysql_select_db('tendesig_production', $dbh2);

    $query = "UPDATE 
                tendesig_dev.euid0_hikashop_product, 
                tendesig_production.euid0_hikashop_product 
            SET 
                tendesig_dev.euid0_hikashop_product.product_quantity = tendesig_production.euid0_hikashop_product.product_quantity
            WHERE 
                tendesig_dev.euid0_hikashop_product.product_id = tendesig_production.euid0_hikashop_product.product_id";
?>
```

Also you don't have to use two connections if both DBs are on the same server

Comment: ok so whith the proper query, the syntax would normally be something like - mysql_query($query, $connection); - but how do i handle this with two connections

Comment: As I said, you don't have to use two connections if both DBs are on the same server, are they ?

Comment: i get the following error now: Error inserting record: SELECT command denied to user 'tendesig_zink'@'localhost' for table 'euid0_hikashop_product'

Comment: This is a permission issue, you should look at the problem with your DBA

Comment: yea i just went into cpanel to check and the user in common between the two databases has SELECT permissions in both databases. hmmmm